# Fn keys stopped working - how can I tell if it's a hardware issue?

Tags: keyboard, laptop, lenovo, thinkpad, function-keys

On my ubuntu 12.04 and Thinkpad T400, I used to adjust brightness by <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> for more brightness or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> for more darkness. But my <kbd>Fn</kbd> key does not work since more than a year ago, not just for adjusting brightness, but also for other things requiring <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

I suspect the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key doesn't work any more.

How can I verify if <kbd>Fn</kbd> key works or not?

Any way to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have a T440s and may be its the same thing: the keyboad top row has two modes, the direct key and the "Fn" + key.

You can switch between the two modes by pressing Fn + FnLk (Esc key on my french keyboard). On my Fn key, a light indicates the mode: when the light is on, I have the F1, F2... in direct mode and I must press Fn to access the special functions like sound, brightness. When the light is off, the special keys are in direct mode and F1, F2, ... in indirect mode (ie I must press Fn to have them).

Hope this helps you.

Giles

Comment: Thanks. Fn+Esc doesn't make any change. For example, with or without it, Fn+Home for adjusting brightness doesn't work